# "H5:H5000" generates type mismatch error in a function that expects a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with specific dates and a dollar value in each line item.

I want to count the lines in each month and for each month create a sum of dollars.

I found a function and modified it:

```
Public Function MonthOppCount(rng As Range, sdate As Date, edate As Date) As Long

    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim MonthCount As Integer
    Dim MonthRev As Long

    For Each Cel In rng
        If Cel >= sdate And Cel < edate Then
            ' MonthCount = MonthCount + 1
            MonthRev = MonthRev + ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
        End If
    Loop

    MonthOppCount = MonthRev
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = MonthCount

End Function
```

I then call the function from another subroutine:

```
Range("P5000").Value = MonthOppCount("H5:H5000", Month1, Month2)
```

I get a type mismatch error with H5:H5000 highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

"H5:H5000" is just a string; VBA doesn't automatically convert it to a range.  Change the line that calls your function from:

```
Range("P5000").Value = MonthOppCount("H5:H5000", Month1, Month2)
```

to:

```
Range("P5000").Value = MonthOppCount(Range("H5:H5000"), Month1, Month2)
```